# Search a std::string

Tags: c++, string

I'm looking to search a string for example:

```
std::string str = "_Data_End__Begin_Data_End";
                  |_________| |_____________|
                      data        data
                    section1     section2
```

If i'm searching for "Begin" in `str` i want to make sure that it does look in "`data section2`" if it wasn't found in "`data section1`"

if i knew the length of "`data section1`" would it be possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?What delimits the two data sections? A standard find _will_ look in "data section2" if the string isn't found in "data section1" as it will scan the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string::find()` has an optional argument to indicate where to begin searching:

```
str.find("Begin", length_of_data_section1);
```

Comment: but what about searching for it in data_section1?

Answer (score 2):

The following code searches the string for "Begin".

```
std::string::size_type loc = str.find("Begin");
if(loc != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "found \"Begin\" at position " << loc << std::endl;
}
```

And because data section2 is at the end of data section1 (and find() begins searching at position0) you don't need any more code.